# jQuery validate with conditional condition between radio buttons

Tags: php, jquery, validation, radio-button

I have a form that I need to validate two radio buttons.

One have a value that will validate the second, where the value of second has to be equal or higher than first.

Exemple: If the value of first is 2, the value of second has to be 2 or higher.

Firts Radio

```
<input name="item1grupoangm" id="item1grupoangm1" type="radio" value="1" />1 &nbsp;
<input name="item1grupoangm" id="item1grupoangm2" type="radio" value="2" />2 &nbsp;
<input name="item1grupoangm" id="item1grupoangm3" type="radio" value="3" />3
```

Second Radio

```
<input name="item1nivelbioseguranca" id="item1nivelbioseguranca1" type="radio" value="1" />1 &nbsp;
<input name="item1nivelbioseguranca" id="item1nivelbioseguranca2" type="radio" value="2" />2 &nbsp;
<input name="item1nivelbioseguranca" id="item1nivelbioseguranca3" type="radio" value="3" />3 &nbsp;
```

I'm trying this:

```
item1nivelbioseguranca: {
    required: true,
    remote: {
        url: "valida_nb_angm.php",
        type: "post",
        data: {
            item1grupoangm: function() {
                return $("input[name='item1grupoangm']:checked").val()
            },
            item1nivelbioseguranca: function() {
                return $("input[name='item1nivelbioseguranca']:checked").val()
            },
        }
    }
},
```

The code of valida_nb_angm.php:

```
  $item1grupoangm = $_POST['item1grupoangm'];
  $item1nivelbioseguranca = $_POST['item1nivelbioseguranca'];

  if ($item1nivelbioseguranca >= $item1grupoangm)
    echo "true";
  else
    echo "false";
```

But it does not work like I want. Only when I submitted the form and if I change the radio, the validation not work until I refresh the page.

I'd like that it work in "real time". If I select the lower value, a message appear and if I select a equal or higher value the form is validated.

Sorry about my English.

Comment: That's how `jQuery.validate` works. It executes the first form validation on form submit by default. Also, for something as simple as this, you probably don't need a `php` to compare 2 values in your page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, add a [custom method](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Validator/addMethod) to `jQuery.validator`:

```
$.validator.addMethod('item1nivelbioseguranca', function() {
    return +$("input[name='item1nivelbioseguranca']:checked").val() >= +$("input[name='item1grupoangm']:checked").val();
}, 'Nível de bio segurança deve ser maior ou igual ao Radio 1');
```

Then set both fields as `required: true` and attach the new custom method to one of them:

```
rules: {
    'item1grupoangm': {
        required: true
    },
    'item1nivelbioseguranca': {
        required: true,
        item1nivelbioseguranca: true
    }
}
```

Then, to make it work realtime, attach a `change` handler to the inputs and just call [`.valid()`](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/valid) on the inputs you want to validate:

```
$('input[name="item1grupoangm"], input[name="item1nivelbioseguranca"]').change(function() {
    var inputs = $('input[name="item1grupoangm"], input[name="item1nivelbioseguranca"]');
    if (inputs.filter(':checked').length === 2) inputs.valid();
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/ult_combo/n8sA7/3/)

Edited to fire the real time validation only after both radios are selected.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have jQuery loaded? If yes, try this:

```
$("input[name='item1nivelbioseguranca']").change(function(){
   var value1=$("input[name='item1grupoangm']:checked").val();
   var value2=$("input[name='item1nivelbioseguranca']:checked").val();
   if ( value2 < value1 ) { 
        alert "Please make sure you select a value larger than item1grupoangm!";
        return false;
   }
});
```

Forgot the reverse part..

```
$("input[name='item1grupoangm']").change(function(){
   var value1=$("input[name='item1grupoangm']:checked").val();
   var value2=$("input[name='item1nivelbioseguranca']:checked").val();
   if ( value2 < value1 ) { 
        alert "Remember to change the value for item1nivelbioseguranca so it is larger than this value!";
   }
});
```